# How to connect Power BI with the website database?

Tags: database, sqlite, powerbi, data-integration

I have a Python -based website hosted on pythonanywhere.com. The website asks for feedback from the user and stores input in sqlite3.

How do I access the website's database in Microsoft Power BI (preferably real-time or periodic otherwise) to display the results?

Comment: Not sure how to do this using Power BI, but if you can screen-scrape the site, Python + BeautifulSoup OR Python + Selenium, would almost certainly do the job for you. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You need the ODBC driver and gateway on your machine. The same user needs to be logged on your machine to make it work. See.
check https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/connecting-a-SQLite-database/td-p/224205

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32856125)